# numpy sum result and transpose on it give same answer

Tags: python, numpy

I'm having some troubles to understand how to do this thing in the right way.

```
print np.sum(X,axis=1)
```

and

```
print np.sum(X,axis=1).T
```

gives me the same result.
What is the best way to fix it?

Why such a thing should not be considered as a bug in numpy?

For example: `X=[[1,2],[3,4]]`.

For first result I wish to get `array([[3,7]])`, and `array([[3],[7]])` for second. can be in the opposite way too..doesnt really matter.

Comment: The default action of `sum` is to reduce the dimensions by 1, in this case, from 2d to 1d.  The transpose of a 1d is itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the extra singleton dimension after computing the sum, you can pass `keepdims=True` to `sum`:

```
X = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]])

print(np.sum(X, axis=0).shape)
# (3,)

print(np.sum(X, axis=0, keepdims=1).shape)
# (1, 3)

print(np.sum(X, axis=1, keepdims=1).shape)
# (2, 1)
```

Apart from using `keepdims`, you could also reshape the output to insert a new axis to replace the one that was lost in the reduction, e.g.:

```
# the '-1' here means that numpy will infer the size in the first dimension to
# match the number of elements in the result array
print(np.sum(X, axis=1).reshape(-1, 1).shape)
# (2, 1)

print(np.sum(X, axis=1)[:, np.newaxis].shape)
# (2, 1)

# indexing with 'None' is equivalent to 'np.newaxis'
print(np.sum(X, axis=1)[:, None].shape)
# (2, 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

I presume you want to transpose first:

```
print np.sum(X.T,axis=1)
```

You are getting a flat array after summing so obviously transposing a 1d array is going to give you the same output as the original array when transposed.

```
In [14]: X=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])    
In [15]: np.sum(X, axis=1)
Out[15]: array([ 6, 15])    
In [16]: np.sum(X, axis=1).T
Out[16]: array([ 6, 15])    
In [17]: np.sum(X.T, axis=1)
Out[17]: array([5, 7, 9])
```

Comment: No problem. BTW, isn't it better just to change the `axis=`?

Comment: no, i want to have array([[6,5]]) in the first result and
array([[6],[5]]). What the best way to reach for that result?

I use it for matrix multiplication and i need to T matrix.

Comment: @AmiTavory, indeed  it is, I just wanted to show the OP that they were getting exactly what they should be getting.

Comment: @member555, not sure I follow,  add your input to your question and expected output

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I'm pretty sure he means 6, **15**.

Comment: @member555, you can use .reshape as per Ami's answer

Answer (score 4):

If it's summing across the wrong axis, why not change it?

```
>> np.sum(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]), axis=1)
array([6, 9])

>> np.sum(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]), axis=0)
array([3, 5, 7])
```

---

**Edit**

You can reshape the resulting array, like this:

```
>> np.sum(np.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]), axis=1).reshape((2, 1))
array([[6],
    [9]])
```

Comment: no, i want to have array([[6,5]]) in the first result and array([[6],[5]]). What the best way to reach for that result? I use it for matrix multiplication and i need to T matrix

Comment: it will be reshape((2,1)) for every input array?

Comment: That means 2 rows, 1 column - the number of rows will depend on your input matrix.

Comment: @member555, not for every input, use the shape of the original array